# Failed to resolve the following : com.github.KwabenBerko:News-API-Java:1.0.0

Tags: android, api, gradle, build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.newsapi"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}


dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.KwabenBerko:News-API-Java:1.0.0'
   and others...
```

The problem:

I am using the NewsApi, which I have Implemented in the build.gradle(module level) of my project. But it is throwing:

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.KwabenBerko:News-API-Java:1.0.0
```

Comment: Add     ```maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }```
 build.gradle file like described in github:  https://github.com/KwabenBerko/News-API-Java

Comment: @SayokMajumder 
I did it still doesn't work:
`
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`

Comment: Try Clean and Rebuild your project